# Flutter: Routing to widgets from a Drawer

Tags: flutter

Is there an example on how to create a draw app & reuse widgets occupying the screen? Yes I know there is an example in the gallery demo app. However that's a bit cheeky because that sample doesn't actually replace, set or change route to a different widget.

I've tried a the new instance of a widget from the onTap event of the drawer item. I've tried having my Getting duplicate global key errors when creating new instances of those widgets when an item is selected from the drawer and the old/new route is pop/pushed

```
ScheduleHomeWidget scheduleWidget = new ScheduleHomeWidget(onSendFeedback: widget.onSendFeedback,);
SpeakerListWidget speakerWidget = new SpeakerListWidget();
var routes = <String, WidgetBuilder> {
  ScheduleHomeWidget.routeName : (BuildContext context) => scheduleWidget,
  SpeakerListWidget.routeName : (BuildContext context) => speakerWidget
};
```

and my MaterialApp:

```
return new MaterialApp(
    title: kAppTitle,
    routes: routes,
    home: scheduleWidget,
);
```

and the code to launch the new route:

```
onTap: () {
    if (routeName != null) {
        Timeline.instantSync('Start Transition', arguments: <String, String>{
            'from': '/',
            'to': routeName
          });
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeName);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not specifying a key when instantiating either the `ScheduleHomeWidget` or the `SpeakerListWidget` instantiation. That said, the `ScheduleHomeWidget` uses an `AnimatedList` which does use a `GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>`

I'll see the following exception:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Flexible(flex: 1):
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
The key [LabeledGlobalKey<AnimatedListState>#d63d7] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of
those widgets were different widgets that both had the following description:
  Flexible(flex: 1)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      GlobalKey._debugReserveFor.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:238:9)
#2      GlobalKey._debugReserveFor (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:219:12)
#3      Element.updateChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2524:13)
#5      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2521:12)
#6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#8      ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3639:5)
#9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#10     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4066:32)
#11     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4448:17)
#12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#15     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3639:5)
#16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#17     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4066:32)
#18     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4448:17)
#19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#20     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#21     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#22     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3639:5)
#23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#24     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#25     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#26     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3528:5)
#27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#28     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4340:14)
#29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#32     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3453:5)
#33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4340:14)
#35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#38     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3528:5)
#39     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#40     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#41     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#42     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3528:5)
#43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#44     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#45     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#46     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3639:5)
#47     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#48     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#49     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#50     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3639:5)
#51     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#52     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#53     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#54     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3528:5)
#55     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2542:15)
#56     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3403:16)
#57     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3292:5)
#58     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2142:33)
#59     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:503:20)
#60     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:189:5)
#61     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:688:15)
#62     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:636:9)
#63     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&RendererBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:275:20)
#65     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:366)
#66     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:394)
#67     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:151)
(elided 3 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async-patch)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 9 of 459 libraries in 2,143ms.
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3727 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1662 pos 12: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true.`
```

This error looks like Flutter is trying to add a widget to the tree by it's ID more than once. Not really trying to do that. Just looking to have two widgets that can take the main focus of the screen. Don't necessarily have to be created a new each time a user selects from the side bar.

Comment: I found an app that dynamically search entries on wikipedia and route them.

I wonder if this example is helpful. I apologize if I cannot help you on your code

https://github.com/nanowang/wiki-flutter

edit: i forgot to add the stocks app for drawer

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/stocks/lib/main.dart#L122

Comment: Great feedback, although I can't get the stocks example to build. Figured out my issue. Apparently, if I would have read the documentation I'd be set. I was looking at two sample widgets that leveraged the [GlobalKey](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) class and per the documentation you can only have one of these instances per app to reparent subtrees of widgets... a feature I don't even need.

Here's a "The More You Know" moment: Reading the documentation pays off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is add a Navigator on `home`. With this setup, you can manage the navigation with a Navigator key.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    drawer: Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: _drawer(),
      ),
    ),
    body: Navigator(
      key: _navigatorKey, // use a Navigator key so the app won't be confused when managing routes
      initialRoute: Nemo.pageA, // Set default page
      ...
    ),
  );
}
```

The Navigator returns the Widget builder of the selected tab.

```dart
Navigator(
  key: _navigatorKey, // use a Navigator key so the app won't be confused when managing routes
  initialRoute: Nemo.pageA, // Set default page
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
    WidgetBuilder builder;
    _currentPage = settings.name;
    // Depending on the route name pushed
    // set the Widget builder to be returned by the Navigator
    // if pushed route is non-existent, return a 404 page
    switch (settings.name) {
      case Nemo.pageA:
        builder = (BuildContext context) => const Center(child: Text('Page A'));
        break;
      case Nemo.pageB:
        builder = (BuildContext context) => const Center(child: Text('Page B'));
        break;
      case Nemo.pageC:
        builder = (BuildContext context) => const Center(child: Text('Page C'));
        break;
      default:
        builder = (BuildContext context) => const Center(child: Text('404'));
    }
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: builder,
      settings: settings,
    );
  },
),
```

On your drawer, you can push the route when the tab has been tapped. Check if the tab tapped is the current page displayed on screen so the same page won't be pushed by the Navigator again.

```dart
List<Widget> _drawer() {
  return <Widget>[
    ListTile(
      title: const Text('Page A'),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        if (_currentPage != Nemo.pageA) {
          _navigatorKey.currentState!
              .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Nemo.pageA, (Route route) => false);
        }
      },
    ),
    ...
  ];
}
```

[image: Demo]

Complete sample

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class Nemo {
  static const String pageA = '/pageA';
  static const String pageB = '/pageB';
  static const String pageC = '/pageC';
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  String? _currentPage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: _drawer(),
        ),
      ),
      body: Navigator(
        key:
            _navigatorKey, // use a Navigator key so the app won't be confused when managing routes
        initialRoute: Nemo.pageA, // Set default page
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          WidgetBuilder builder;
          _currentPage = settings.name;
          // Depending on the route name pushed
          // set the Widget builder to be returned by the Navigator
          // if pushed route is non-existent, return a 404 page
          switch (settings.name) {
            case Nemo.pageA:
              builder =
                  (BuildContext context) => const Center(child: Text('Page A'));
              break;
            case Nemo.pageB:
              builder =
                  (BuildContext context) => const Center(child: Text('Page B'));
              break;
            case Nemo.pageC:
              builder =
                  (BuildContext context) => const Center(child: Text('Page C'));
              break;
            default:
              builder =
                  (BuildContext context) => const Center(child: Text('404'));
          }
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: builder,
            settings: settings,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _drawer() {
    return <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        title: const Text('Page A'),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          if (_currentPage != Nemo.pageA) {
            _navigatorKey.currentState!
                .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Nemo.pageA, (Route route) => false);
          }
        },
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: const Text('Page B'),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          if (_currentPage != Nemo.pageB) {
            _navigatorKey.currentState!
                .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Nemo.pageB, (Route route) => false);
          }
        },
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: const Text('Page C'),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          if (_currentPage != Nemo.pageC) {
            _navigatorKey.currentState!
                .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Nemo.pageC, (Route route) => false);
          }
        },
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```